# How to use render_block filter in Gutenberg when editing a page?

Tags: filters, block-editor, actions

I am trying to add new content after updating a page. I've tried the code below, which doesn't seem to have any effect.

I've tried `core/paragraph` and `core/code` in the `if statement` below but still no luck.

```
function my_render_block( string $block_content, array $block) {
    if ($block['blockName'] === 'core/paragraph') {
        $block_content = '<div class="paragraph">New paragraph ';
        $block_content .= $block_content;
        $block_content .= '</div>';
    }
    
    return $block_content;
}

function my_edit_post_hook($post_id) {
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    
    add_filter('render_block', 'my_render_block', 10, 2);
}
add_action('edit_post', 'my_edit_post_hook', 10, 2);
```

Would `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content )` work in Gutenberg? I also tried this but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `render_block` only runs when the block is displayed on the frontend, that `add_filter` would only work if you edited the post and then displayed it to the user in the same request, and only if that displaying happened after the post was edited, which would never happen. What are you trying to do and what problem does that solve? The code you've shared is unfixable, but that doesn't mean your original problem can't be solved

Comment: also if it did work, all paragraphs would look like this because you're replacing the variable then trying to reuse it: `<div class="paragraph">New paragraph <div class="paragraph">New paragraph </div>`, all paragraphs would be replaced with that

Comment: @TomJNowell Perhaps my approach was wrong. I am wanting to replace the page content programmatically when the Update button is pressed on the page.